# JSX not showing in browser

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux, react-router, django-react

Hi there I recently started following a crash course of Django Rest Framework + React but I came across a problem with my React code. The jsx I write in my `App.js` doesn't show in the browser. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Header from './layout/Header';
import Dashboard from './leads/Dashboard';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Header />
                <div>
                    <Dashboard />
                </div>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

He are my `Header.js`, and `Dashboard.js` files(in case it helps)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Django + React</a>
                        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Header;
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import Leads from './Leads';

export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form />
      <Leads />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In case you need any extra information please tell me. Can anyone please help me solve this problem?? If so please tell me and thank you in advance.

Edit: Here is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "DjangoReact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch ./backend/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./backend/frontend/static/frontend",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./backend/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./backend/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^5.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-react": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What steps did you take? Did you run `npm start`?

Comment: I tried but it gives me an error. "missing script: start"

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file and are you running this in directory where package.json lives?

Comment: I edited my post to show the package.json file and no I am not running them in the same directory (in the same root folder but not in the same directory)

Comment: try `npm run dev`

Comment: I did but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

You will not see jsx files in the browser. The code from jsx files is transformed into html+js code and displayed in the web browser.

Before going to write your own code, please make sure that you have `node.js` installed and that you can run React template code:

```sh
# create the React boilerplate project
npx create-react-app frontend

# go to the fronted project directory
cd frontend

# run React built-in development server
npm start
```

After the above commands, you should see a default web app at `http://localhost:3000`.

You can check details in my article: [Starting SaaS with Django and React](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/django-react-boilerplate-saas/)

If you are able to see the default application then you can start to add your code. Here you have the second part of my article: [React Routing and Components for Signup and Login](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/react-routing-components-signup-login/)